# JEST - unexpected token import while running test

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jestjs, babel-jest

Im writing tests for an application but i run into the following error when importing certain classes in my tests:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/node_modules/react-redux/es/connect/connect.js:5
import connectAdvanced from '../components/connectAdvanced';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
 9 |     children: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
10 |     translator: PropTypes.func.isRequired
11 | };
   |             ^
```

I have not written any tests yet, i only imported the component in my test file:

```
import {TheComponent} from '../src/components/the-component';
```

My jest.config.json looks like this:

```
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "setupFiles": [
    "raf/polyfill",
    "<rootDir>/test/testSetup.js"
  ]
}
```

My .babelrc file looks like this and is in the root directory:

```
{
  "presets": [ "react", "es2015", "stage-2" ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
    ]
}
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "testError",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test:jest": "jest --config=jest.config.json --watchAll"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "prettier": "^1.13.7",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.5.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4",
    "yargs": "^12.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eventing-bus": "^1.3.3",
    "filesize": "^3.6.1",
    "i18next": "^11.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "react": "^16.4",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0",
    "react-truncate": "^2.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.22.1"
  },
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "module": "src/index.js"
}
```

I have tried to put several values in both the transformIgnorePatterns and transform properties in .babelrc but so for no luck.
Does anyone know how i can solve this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could it be you need https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import?

Comment: I think you have 2 options, you could either move to require syntax:

1 - const connectAdvanced = require('../components/connectAdvanced')

or

2 - use *babel-jest* to transpile https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest

Comment: Please share your `testSetup.js` and '../src/components/the-component' files. I've just set up an environment with the config that you described in the question and it works without any errors.

Comment: I added the following to my jest.config file and it worked: 
` "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(react-redux|lodash-es)/)"
  ]
`

Answer (score 1):

As Mitch commented above,

> I added the following to my jest.config file and it worked: `"transformIgnorePatterns": [ "node_modules/(?!(react-redux|lodash-es)/)" ]`